# Github - cant find my android project after trying to upload with bash command

Tags: android, bash, github

I have develop an android application. i tried to upload it to github with bash command.
for some reason it didnt work, but its not the problem. the problem is that now i cant find my project. when i active Android Studio it does not find my project.
what should i do? how can i undo what i did?
I have tried to search how to resolve the problem, but unfortunately i didnt find anything
sorry that i didnt upload any pice of code or pictures, but if it indeed please let me know so i would upload whatever needed.

Comment: Try to open build.gradle file in the project folder with Android studio

Comment: Upload to github using which command?

Comment: first i did " git commit  -m 'my project name' " and then i did " git remote add origin remote repository URL "

Comment: just do a 'git push'

Comment: i did it but it didnt worked, and it seems like it stuck. in the Github bash when i try to commit another project its says: " Another git process seems to be running in this repository, an editor opened by 'git commit'... "

Answer (score 0):

**There Are a few ways you can solve this**

**1...**
I don't know the command you used but somehow, you've moved the project from the default workspace configured for android studio. If you're on windows, try using the GitHub [windows client](http://windows.github.com/). When you run it, you can see all directories with github and figure out what exactly you did. If you find the directory that contains your project, just copy your project from that directory to your workspace.

**2..** If you know your project directory, check it out and if you find the project in there, Make sure Android Studio workspace is configured to look in the right directory.

**3...** Finally, If you still can't figure it out, Open Android Studio, click on open Recent and it should list your project there. Click on it and if it opens, then congratulations.. else you'll get an error which will help you figure out what you actually did. 
But as i said, I don't know the command you tried to run so this is the best i can give.